# count numbers between L and R which have atleast one prime factor between 1 to 50

Tags: algorithm, math, primes

Given L and R very large numbers (10^18) , how do i find count of numbers between L and R such that numbers have atleast one prime factors from 1 to N.

Note : N can be at MAX 50

Comment: can you give an example in smaller numbers?

Comment: How big can N be? Are L and R expected to be close to each other?

Comment: @MarkDickinson  2<=N<=50

Answer (score 1):

I will just sketch a method, not working it out in detail.

If R-L is very small it is probably best to try it out one by one.

Otherwise use the [inclusion exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle): For explanation reasons I just consider the primes 2,3, and 5. Determine how many numbers can be divided by 2, 3, 5 (i.e. one of the primes), 6, 10, 15 (i.e. two of the primes), and 30 (i.e. all three of the primes). For a divisor `k` this is approximately `(R-L)/k`, taking the border conditions into account, we can get the exact count. Call the respective count c(k).

Now the total count of numbers divisible by at least one prime is:

```
c(2)+c(3)+c(5)-c(6)-c(10)-c(15)+c(30)
```